# ReactJS state array pushing issues

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array in a react state hook. I'm pushing values to it in a way that i assumed was the correct way, yet the array is always empty when i try to log it. What about my method of pushing to the array is not correct?

```
const [betHistory, setBetHistory] = useState([""]);
```

Inside my function (which i've tested is being called, and betCount is never blank)

```
function placeBet() {
  console.log(betCount);
  setBetHistory(betHistory => [...betHistory, betCount.toString()]);
  console.log(betHistory);
}
```

The log is always blank.

Comment: `betHistory` should be updated on the next render, not immediately where you have the log.  Try logging `betHistory` at the top of the render function.

Comment: BTW you have two variables in scope called `betHistory`, eg. the parameter could be renamed `setBetHistory(oldBetHistory => [...oldBetHistory, betCount.toString()]);`.  This is just to avoid confusion.

Comment: setBetHistory takes an array not a function.... also you might better off creating a variable to hold the new array const newArr = [...betHistory];  the call newArr.push(betCount.toString()) then setBetHistory(newArr)........... Also why are you using an array? an array of only one thing?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro it can take the data value (array in this case) or a function, so that part of the code is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the state will update the value on the next render, not immediately. If you need to access the updated value right away, store it in a variable:

```
function placeBet() {
  const newBetHistory = [...betHistory, betCount.toString()];
  setBetHistory(newBetHistory);
  console.log(newBetHistory);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed the log from newBetHistory to betHistory, and it logs fine, shows all the values that were pushed. Can you think of a reason why if i have console.log(betHistory) in another function thats called after a few values have been pushed, in that function the log is blank again, as if no values were pushed. Despite the log in placeBet() showing values?

Comment: The other function, is called by a parent through the use of useRef, btw. Terrible design I know but why when the parent calls the function that logs betHistory, is it blank again, despite values being pushed?

Comment: "called after a few values have been pushed" -- but is it in the same call to render?  It's the **next** render where you'd expect to see the updated value in `betHistory`

Comment: Hi, i'm not calling any render function? My parent and child are functional components, in my index.js there is a call to render with the parent in it, parent has the child in its jsx

Comment: OK  then your "render function" is really just the body of an anonymous function.   Try logging `betHistory` immediately after the `useState` and I bet you'll see the correct value show up after you set the value.

Comment: Hi, i explained it more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875707/reactjs-parent-child-ref-has-outdated-child-state