# ReactJS parent child ref has outdated child state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using `useRef()` to call a childs function from my parent component. The issue is the childs state (`betHistory`) is empty whenever the parent calls the childs `undo` function, but when `undo()` is called by the child itself, the state is in date (filled with all the values that have been pushed to it). Why is my parent seeing an empty version of `betHistory` when calling `undo()` vs when `undo()` is called by the child itself?

Parent

```
import './App.css';
import Table from './Table';
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

function App() {
  const table = useRef();

  function undo() {
    table.current.undo();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="table-section">
        <Table ref={table}></Table>
      </div>
      <div className="button" onClick={undo}>Click me</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Child

```
import React, { useState, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
import './Table.css';

function Table(props, ref) {

  const [betHistory, setBetHistory] = useState([]);
  const [betCount, setBetCount] = useState(0);


  function placeBet(element) {
    const newBetHistory = [...betHistory, betCount.toString()];
    setBetHistory(newBetHistory);
    setBetCount((1 + betCount));
  }

  function undo() {
    console.log(betHistory);
  }

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    undo() {
      undo();
    }
  }), [])

  return (
    <div className="button" onClick={undo}>Click me</div>
    <div className="bet-button" onClick={placeBet}></div>
  );
}

export default forwardRef(Table)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    undo() {
      undo();
    }
  }), []) // ---> Try remove this []
```

It has to do with the empty array you specified. Try removing it. Just like in `useEffect` when you specify empty array as dependency it will run only once, *so the function captured inside is from first render*, hence you don't see recent data.

Or you can specify correct dependencies.

Comment: If it's a dependency array issue, it seems that removing the array entirely would be an overcorrection--OP would just need to add `undo` to the array (and probably memoize the `undo` function iteself)

Comment: @Nick Yeah he can, but I also don't see much problem in just removing the dependencies array.